# Неверный ответ от webhook TelegramBot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, telegram, asp.net-web-api

Проект asp.net.core 5.0 web-api.
Внутри проекта создал контроллер с методом, которого должен дергать TelegramBot, а он в ответ оправлять ответ в чат:

```
    [ApiController]
        [Route("api/TelegramListener")]
        public class TelegramListenerController : ControllerBase
        {
     private readonly ILogger<TelegramListenerController> _logger;
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private TelegramBotClient telegramBotClient;
        private string currentPath;
        private string _token { get; set; } = "19чч785959:ччччч";       

            
            public TelegramListenerController(ILogger<TelegramListenerController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            telegramBotClient = new TelegramBotClient(_token);
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            currentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        }
    [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Update update)
            {
List<string> listlogs = new List<string>();
            listlogs.Add(update.ToString());
            ReadWriteFileTxt.WriteFile(listlogs, currentPath, "logs "+ DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('.', '_').Replace(' ', '_').Replace(':', '_'), "txt");

                var message = update.Message;
                if (message != null)
                {
                    MessageData requestMessage = new MessageData { TextMessage = message.Text, PhoneNumber = message.Contact.PhoneNumber, UserName = message.Contact.FirstName };
    
                    await telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, message.Contact.PhoneNumber, replyToMessageId: message.MessageId);
                }
    
                return Ok();
            }
    }
```

Зарегистрировал:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot195285959:ххххххххlk/setwebhook?url=https://messager.хххх.рф/api/TelegramListener
```

Регистрация прошла.

Потом запросил информацию:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot1956785959:AAHbzkyMAzp6b6houFkvZyAMoPVgK5hxmlk/getWebhookInfo
```

Получил 500 ошибку:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://messager.\u043e\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0432\u0441\u0435.\u0440\u0444/api/TelegramListener","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":2,"last_error_date":1632146544,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 500 Internal Server Error","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"чч.ччччч.100"}}
```

Попробовал протестировать в режиме отладки с помощью ngrok. Точка остановы в контроллере не срабатывает, хотя вроде как слушает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://c0bb-195-226-209-21.ngrok.io/api/TelegramListener","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":6,"last_error_date":1632203484,"last_error_message":"Wrong
> response from the webhook: 503 Service
> Unavailable","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"3.14.182.203"}}

Запрос через Postman проходит только с заголовком `UserSecretId`, без него пишет что `Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent.`.

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TLmessanger", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TLmessanger v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            //Add
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Нашел ещё, что `Telegram API only supports the ports 443, 80, 88 or 8443.`, в режиме отладки у меня не получается запустить на этих портах получается на 44315, может причина в этом:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:35145",
      "sslPort": 44315
    }
```

При отправке в режиме отладки через swagger VS, запрос попадает в нужный
метод контроллера и отрабатывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму где ошибка? Подскажите.

Comment: А что отвечает SendMessages? Где его HTTP ответ? В коде вообще ничего нет. Также приведите что выдает вызов SendTextMessageAsync.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov разве это не считается ответом ```// Ответ в чат-бот 
                await telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, message.Contact.PhoneNumber, replyToMessageId: message.MessageId);```?

Comment: Что отдает SendTextMessageAsync в результате по [прямому вызову](https://www.xibel-it.eu/debug-telegram-bot-sdk-with-webhook-in-laravel/) вашего https://messager.хххх.рф/api/TelegramListener?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, попробовал протестировать с ngrok (дополнил вопрос описанием), такое ощущение, что запросы до метода не доходят

Comment: Когда-то проходил такой же этап, что было непонятно, пришёл запрос или нет - просто включал логирование. Пишите в файлы/базу данных/почту - что у вас под рукой проще взять.

Comment: @AK, особо плохо, что не проходят запросы через Postman and ngrock, даже не посмотришь, что там происходит

Comment: @AK, а в ```Startup.cs ``` нужно, что-то дополнительное прописывать кроме ```services.AddControllers()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson();```, а то может что-то упустил?

Comment: @AK, добавил logger в контроллер и метод создающий текстовый файл и записывающий в него строки, но не знаю, что писать туда?

Comment: Примечание. Вы же вроде правильно создавали раньше HttpClient с помощью фабрики (в предыдущих вопросах у вас было что-то такое). А сейчас неправильно создаёте новые экземпляры на каждый запрос. Вернитесь к использования IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, так там я в итоге обошелся HttpClient, IHttpClientFactory просто проинициализировал, но не использовал. Здесь я его создаю для другой цели, в дальнейшем буду пересылать запрос на API другого сервиса, но это потом.  А разве сейчас он для Телеграм бота нужен?

Comment: Почему у вас используется ngrok и прочая ерунда? Вы не можете чтоль напрямую запустить проект у себя на компьютере и посмотреть, как работает API через тот же Postman или что? Вот прям в студии запустите проект, он вам откроет `http://localhost:1111`, вот этот адрес берете и впихиваете в Postman, пытаясь отправить запросы. Также поставьте в студии брекпоинт и шаг за шагом проследите как работает метод. Серьезно, вы сейчас кучу лишнего делаете, что скорей всего и приводит к проблеме. Забудьте про домен и забудьте про телеграмм, сделайте первым делом рабочий API метод!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, при отправке в режиме отладки через swagger VS, запрос попадает в нужный метод контроллера и отрабатывает (дополнил ответ в конце описанием). Для отправки через  Postman пришлось добавить заголовок ```UserSecretId```, может причина в этом?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, как  исключить заголовок ```UserSecretId```?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Я не вижу, чтоб [тут было](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRx2g.png) хоть какое-либо упоминание про некий `UserSecretId`, от куда вы вообще его взяли? Вы уверены, что именно он требуется? Запросы одинаковые? Не может сервер просить разные данные для разных клиентов... Да и метод у вас "голый", без каких-либо проверок или чего-либо еще. Ищите значит от куда это взялось, избавляйтесь или правьте. И да, советую начать с правки косяков, например почему у вас 2 раза `services.AddControllers() `? Зачем `AddNewtonsoftJson()`? Что за ужас тут `DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace`?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir По поводу `HttpClient` - огромный косяк, ибо если зайдете в документацию, то увидите "один объект на все приложение". Сейчас у вас 1 клиент для сервера Api, 2 клиент для телеграмм бота, и 3 вы создали сами. Вам правильно сказали выше - используйте фабрику, чтоб был один клиент, который вы будете использовать везде. Даже вон [инициализация](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/src/Telegram.Bot/TelegramBotClient.cs#L72) телеграмм бота принимает `HttpClient`. И да, приведите пожалуйста вопрос в порядок, убрав лишнее, добавив нужное и исправив форматирование.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ```UserSecretId``` отображается в IDEA в свойствах проекта, там я его и увидел и подумал, что его нужно передать в заголовке, и да без него запрос из Postman не работал - выдавал `Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent.`. Откуда он там взялся и как от него избавится не знаю

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, AddNewtonsoftJson() это для JSON, просто ```services.AddControllers()``` удалил

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ```DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace```, это я пытаюсь создать файл с логами для хостинга, чтобы посмотреть проходят запросы или нет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, почему `Сейчас у вас 1 клиент для сервера Api, 2 клиент для телеграмм бота, и 3 вы создали сами.`? Я же создаю его 1-н раз - в конструкторе контроллера?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, c прохождением запросов справился: нужно было из ```Starup.cs ``` убрать ```app.UseAuthorization()```, которая включается по умолчанию при создании проекта, а в ```launchsettings.json``` отключить "sslPort" - ```"sslPort": 0```. И  тогда он перестает требовать в заголовках запроса  заголовок ```UserSecretId```.  У меня остался вопрос по ```HttpClient```, подскажите как мне правильно описать/создать, чтобы я мог и принимать запросы от Телеграмм и пересылать их по http на другой сервер, и принимать ответ?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir `AddNewtonsoftJson() это для JSON`  - в C# есть свой парсер JSON, который Microsoft везде используют. Так задайте себе вопрос, зачем вам сторонний парсер вдруг надо подключать (`Newtonsoft` - сторонняя библиотека, не от Microsoft)? `Я же создаю его 1-н раз` - Ага, а как вы думаете сам asp.net работает? Правильно, создает свой экземляр `HttpClient`, а как `TelegramBotClient` работает? Правильно, тоже создает свой собственный `HttpClient` (ссылку на исходинк давал выше). Вот и получаете как минимум 3 клиента.

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir `У меня остался вопрос по HttpClient, подскажите как мне правильно описать/создать` - примерно [так](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests). Обратите внимание на метод `.CreateClient()`, он вам если надо, создат новый, либо вернет уже существующий клиент для всех ваших нужд. Не забудьте в бота передать (нечто, на подобии `telegramBotClient = new(_token, client);`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо! Оформите в ответ, отмечу

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Я, пожалуй, воздержусь от этого. Вы можете сами ответом оформить то, как решили проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда у меня была подобного рода проблема, её суть заключалась в `UseHttpsRedirection()`. Когда вы получаете запрос через ngrok `https://c0bb-195-226-209-21.ngrok.io/api/TelegramListener` на ваш сервер, где указан протокол **HTTP** — `http://localhost:44352`, middleware `UseHttpsRedirection` редиректит запрос на **HTTPS**, который запущен на другом порту.

Попробуйте убрать вызов `UseHttpsRedirection()` в `Startup`, если вы его используете, чтобы проект мог корректно работать по **HTTP**.

Comment: Telegram bot работает только через https

Comment: Как раз таки чтобы обеспечить HTTPS и используется ngrok. чтобы локальный HTTP телеграм воспринимал как HTTPS. И еще телеграм бот может работать по HTTP, но вот вебхуки работают только по HTTPS (который предоставляет нам ngrok).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что запросы не доходили до метода контроллера из-за требования указания в заголовках запросы заголовка `UserSecretId`, который телеграмбот не отправляет. Это связано с тем, что по умолчанию при создании проекта в классе `Startup.cs` прописывается внедрение зависимости `app.UseAuthorization()`, а в файле настроек запуска приложения `launchsettings.json` прописывается `sslPort`. Необходимо удалить зависимость
`app.UseAuthorization()`, а порт ssl установить - `"sslPort": 0`, тогда требования наличия заголовка `UserSecretId` не будет.

Comment: Ответ странный: я сравнил со своим проектом и в нём присутствует UseAuthorization и sslPort установлен в ненулевое значение. Это хорошо что у вас работает, но поскольку вы не особо разобрались - то это похоже что вы навели себе пистолет на ногу, осталось только подождать, когда выстрелит. Ну, будем надеяться что до выстрела не дойдёт, но всё же вы б разобрались... Гораздо лучше, когда вы понимаете как ваш код работает, чем когда просто "вот какой-то код, добились что работает - но стараемся не дышать, что не поломалось"

Comment: @AK, а каково ваше предположение почему запросы не проходили?

Comment: Непонимание инфраструктуры конкретного провайдера и попытка нащупать взаимодействие с конкретным поставщиком (а значит при смене снова начнёте по граблям ходить).

Comment: @AK, не понял вас, можно попроще объяснить?